# Tikz grid with inverted vertical axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I inverted the vertical axis in `Tikz` for convenience, and then tried to draw a simple grid:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
    \draw[step=1] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For some reason I got all the vertical lines and one horizontal line:

[image]

Dropping the `[y=-1cm]` bit gives me the desired output:

[image]

Is it a bug?  How can I keep the inverted vertical axis while drawing a grid?

Comment: Do you not get a compilation error? Can you please post a complete example? When I try to complete yours with a minimal wrapper, it does not compile at all.

Comment: Your code produces an error. What you are trying to do can be achieved with `\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \draw[step=1] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: I edited the question with the entire code.  Have no issues with compiling it (MiKTeX, pdflatex)...

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, your solution also works for me, thank you!

Comment: @Zarko This looks like a bug to me. If it is not, how can we explain that replacing `[y=-1cm]` with `[yscale=-1]` works fine ?

Answer (score 2):

I actually managed to fix the problem by changing the vertical step to -1 and swapping the `y` coordinates of the grid:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
    \draw[xstep=1,ystep=-1] (0,4) grid (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but to me this looks like a bug in `Tikz`.

Comment: A bug? I doubt. I thing that you request from TikZ two opposite action at the same time, and this confuse it. It cannot be posivite steps with negative value ...